# How can I hide lines from the axes of my bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to hide the lines that are in the axes of my graph to try to match it with this image.[image]

This is my current result.

[image]

How can I do it?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      padding: {
          left: 60
      },
      data: {
          x: 'x',
          columns:
          [
              ['x', 'Category1', 'Category2','Categoia3'],
              ['value', 300, 400,700]
          ],
          type: 'bar'
      },
      axis: {
          rotated: true,
          x: {
              type: 'category'
          }
      }
 }
);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IzkGUsluWwxrGpgX8gte?p=preview

Comment: Add `.tick line {
  display:none;
}` to your css and it will do the trick

Comment: put this as a answer please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

`.tick line { display:none; }`

in your css to make all the ticks disappear, works for both `c3.js` and `d3.js`

Comment: can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577517/how-can-i-give-a-padding-to-move-the-text-away-from-the-categories